# How to compare Json data with array using Shell Script?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq, string-comparison

I have one json e.g

```
var bbview ={  
   "tbl_am_api":[  
      {  
         "Modified_User":"user1",
         "Modified_Time":"04-Jul-2018 01:40:05",
         "Line_Number":"SS001",
         "Service_Type":"BB3",
         "Status":"Yes",
         "ID":3144526000014337832,
         "Added_Time":"04-May-2018 11:37:29"
      },
      {  
         "Modified_User":"user2",
         "Modified_Time":"04-Jul-2018 01:40:05",
         "Line_Number":"SS002",
         "Service_Type":"BB2",
         "Status":"Yes",
         "ID":3144526000014337832,
         "Added_Time":"04-May-2018 11:37:29"
      },
      {  
         "Modified_User":"user3",
         "Modified_Time":"04-Jul-2018 01:40:05",
         "Line_Number":"SS004",
         "Service_Type":"BB1",
         "Status":"No",
         "ID":3144526000014337832,
         "Added_Time":"04-May-2018 11:37:29"
      }
   ]
};
```

I want to compare this json data and array. Primary key as Line Number.

```
arrayA = {[{Line_Number : SS001, Service_Type : BB3; Status : Yes}]}
```

arrayA have Line_Number SS001. Find this Line_Number in json and compare Service_Type value and Status value are same or not. I want to write with Shell Script in bash file. I am not proficient in shell script. Please help me.

Update:
I tried with following bash code. But still fail. Please advice me

```
echo "Download FMS AM API File"
rm -rf tbl_am_api_Report?authtoken=da84d49f334c33b88d30dd2c947a4ff0 && wget -q https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/fixed-management-system/view/tbl_am_api_Report?authtoken=da84d49f334c33b88d30dd2c947a4ff0&scope=creatorapi&zc_ownername=tmlbroadband < /dev/null

cat > tbl_api_Report?authtoken=da84d49f334c33b88d30dd2c947a4ff0 //read json file
for row in $(echo "${apiview}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
    _jq() {
     echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
    }

   echo $(_jq '.name') >> info.txt
done

mail -s "Test email" aa@gmail.com -A info.txt < /dev/null
```

Comment: 1. Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. (What is the expected output?) 2. The code under "Update" seems to be completely irrelevant at best, and gibberish at worst.  I'd suggest removing it, otherwise your Q will probably be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

The value of arrayA is not JSON so I am going to let you figure out how to extract the values of Line_Number and Status from arrayA (but see below).  Once those values are available, one could proceed as illustrated here:

```
#!/bin/bash

bbview='...' # as above

echo "$bbview" |
  jq --arg Line_Number SS001 --arg Status Yes '
    .tbl_am_api
    | map(select(.Line_Number==$Line_Number and .Status==$Status)) '
```

### Output

```
[
  {
    "Modified_User": "user1",
    "Modified_Time": "04-Jul-2018 01:40:05",
    "Line_Number": "SS001",
    "Service_Type": "BB3",
    "Status": "Yes",
    "ID": 3144526000014338000,
    "Added_Time": "04-May-2018 11:37:29"
  }
]
```

### true/false

Under a different reading of the question, the following variant might be relevant:

```
echo "$bbview" |
  jq --arg Line_Number SS001 --arg Status Yes '
    .tbl_am_api
    | map(select(.Line_Number==$Line_Number) | .Status==$Status) '
```

### arrayA

If you are using a version of bash that supports associative arrays, you could define arrayA as an associative array, like so:

```
declare -A arrayA
arrayA=([Line_Number]=SS001 [Service_Type]=BB3 [Status]=Yes)
```

Then to retrieve the value associated with Line_Number, you would write: `${arrayA[Line_Number]}`; etc.